# Update Layout Parameters for existing object

Tags: android, view

I use setLayoutParams to set layout parameters for an object of a custom view I made like below:

```
MyCustomView object = new ObjectView(getApplicationContext());
                object.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

How can I change or update this LayoutParams for the same object programmatically at run time ?

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Can you elaborate??

Comment: @Vickyexpert I want to reset width and height again (override the original ones)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset or change parameters dynamically later like below code:

```
MyCustomView object = new ObjectView(getApplicationContext());
object.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



public void manageViewParams(int width, int height)
{
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParam = object.getLayoutParams();
   layoutParam.width = width;
   layoutParam.height = height;

   //first check without this below line, it should work. If not then you need to write below line
   object.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);
}
```

Comment: there is no setHeight or Width in layoutParam

Comment: @Hussein you have to cast it. For example `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`. It depends on the view group you are using. If you are using LinearLayout you can cast it into `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int yourHeight = 200;
int yourWidth = 200;

MyCustomView object = new ObjectView(getApplicationContext());
//this
object.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        yourHeight,
                        yourWidth));
//or this
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        yourHeight,
                        yourWidth));
object.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);
```

Comment: this will crash the program because the object is already have layoutParams 
And I do not want to create a new object